# Using GithubWeb in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

How can I use `GithubWeb` class available in Jenkins Pipeline to get the links for changes/commits that have been caught for the current build and are available in the `currentBuild.changeSets`?